# Bind the record to html.dropdownlist using ajax call in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have one Mvc application. In that application in one View  i have 2 @html.dropdownlists.I create one function in `<script/>` tag, will call at selectedIdnexchange event of first dropdown, and get the selected value and send to controller using ajax call. Controller will return result and trying to bind that result with 2nd dropdown.I want to display all RTO names of selected state in 2nd dropdown.
Here is my  dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("State", new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Andaman and Nicobar Islands",Value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Andhra Pradesh",Value="Andhra Pradesh"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Arunachal Pradesh",Value="Arunachal Pradesh"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Assam",Value="Assam"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Bihar",Value="Bihar"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Chandigarh",Value="Chandigarh"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Chhattisgarh",Value="Chhattisgarh"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Dadra and Nagar Haveli",Value="Dadra and Nagar Haveli"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Daman and Diu",Value="Daman and Diu"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="National Capital Territory of Delhi",Value="National Capital Territory of Delhi"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Goa",Value="Goa"} }, null, new { @class="ddlHtml form-control",@id="ddlState"})
@Html.DropDownList("RTOListItem", new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                                                     new SelectListItem{Text="None",Value="-1"}
                                                                     }, null, new { @class = "ddlHtml form-control", @id = "DDlforLocations" })
```

Here is my script function

```
 $(document).on('change', '#ddlState', function () {
     var v = document.getElementById("ddlState");
     var statevalue = v.options[v.selectedIndex].text;
     alert(statevalue);
     var j = v.selectedIndex;
     if (j == 0) {
         sweetAlert("Oops..", "choose correct State", "error");
     }
     else {
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("GetLocations","Home")',
             type: 'GET',
             datatype: 'json',
             data: { selectedState: statevalue }
         })
            .success(function (data) {
                $('#DDlforLocations').html(data);
            });
     }
 });
```

And here is my controller

public JsonResult GetLocations(string selectedState)
        {

```
        ConsumerNomineeFormEntities db= new ConsumerNomineeFormEntities();
        RTOCode tbl = new RTOCode();
        var optionList = db.RTOCodes.Where(a => a.State == selectedState).Select(a => "<option value='" + a.Location + "'>" + a.Location + "</option>");

        var val = tbl.Location;


        return Json(optionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Please help me. To bind the record returning from controller with 2nd dropdown

Comment: What is your question? Problem?

Comment: @FelixCen When i am selecting item from 1st dropdown , it will call one function that contain ajax call for sending my item value to controller and controller will return result to ajax call. now i want to bind that result to 2nd dropdown as a value and text of dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good idea to mix the code to build your UI markup in your server side code. You may consider returning some **data** from your server side which you will use in your client side to build the UI markup.

So let's return a list of SelectListItem objects.

```
var optionList = db.RTOCodes.Where(a => a.State == selectedState)
       .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Location, 
                                         Text = c.Location}).ToList();
```

And in your ajax call's success event, loop through this array and build the markup for the options.

```
success : function(data){
  var options="";
  // options = "<option value='-1'>None</option>"; // uncomment if you want this item
  $.each(data,function(a,b){
    options+="<option value='"+b.Value+"'>"+b.Text+"</option>";
  });
  $("#DDlforLocations").html(options);
}
```

Also, since you are loading the content of the second dropdown via ajax when user selects something on the first dropdown, you may consider changing that to **pure clean HTML**

```
<select name="RTOListItem" id="DDlforLocations">
    <option value="-1">Select one</option>
</select>
```